# Stratified Sampling with different sizes

Tags: pandas, sampling

I am trying to create a function for stratified sampling which takes in a dataframe created using the faker module along with strata, sample size and a random seed. For the sample size, I want the number of samples in each strata to vary based on user input. This is my code for creating the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as rn#generating random numbers
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()
frame_fake = pd.DataFrame( [{"region": 
fake.random_number(1,fix_len=True),
                    "district": fake.random_number(2,fix_len=True),
                    "enum_area": fake.random_number(5,fix_len=True),
                    "hhs": fake.random_number(3),
                    "pop": fake.random_number(4),
                    "area": fake.random_number(1)} for x in range(100)])
# check for and remove duplicates from enum area (should be unique) 
# before any further analysis
mask= frame_fake.duplicated('enum_area', keep='last')
duplicates = frame_fake[mask]
# print(duplicates)

# drop all except last
frame_fake = frame_fake.drop_duplicates('enum_area',         
keep='last').sort_values(by='enum_area',ascending=True)
# reset index to have them sequentially after sorting by enum_area and     
# drop the old index column
frame_fake = frame_fake.reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
frame_fake
```

This is the code for sampling:

```
def stratified_custom(data,strata,sample_size, seed=None):
# for this part, we sample 5 enum areas in each strata/region
# we groupby strata and use the transform method with 'count' parameter     
# to get strata sizes
data['strat_size'] = data.groupby(strata)[strata].transform('count')
# map input sample size to each strata
data['strat_sample_size'] = data[strata].map(sample_size)
# grouby strata, get sample size per stratum, cast to int and reset 
# index.
smp_size = data.groupby(strata)    
['strat_sample_size'].unique().astype(int).reset_index()
# groupby strata and select sample per stratum based on the sample size 
# for that strata
sample = (data.groupby(strata, group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.sample(smp_size,random_state=seed)))
# probability of inclusion
sample['inclusion_prob'] = 
sample['strat_sample_size']/sample['strat_size']
return sample
s_size={1:7,2:5,3:5,4:5,5:5,6:5,7:5,8:5,9:8} #pass in strata and sample 
# size as dict. (key, values)
(stratified_custom(data=frame_fake,strata='region',sample_size=s_size, 
seed=99).sort_values(by=['region','enum_area'],ascending=True))
```

I however receive this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I can't figure out what this error is talking about. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I stumbled upon this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794577/14198137 and implemented this in my code to not only sample based on varying sample sizes but also with fixed ones using the same function. Here is my code for the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as rn 
from faker import Faker
Faker.seed(99)
fake = Faker()
frame_fake = pd.DataFrame( [{"region": 

fake.random_number(1,fix_len=True),"district": 
fake.random_number(2,fix_len=True),"enum_area": 
fake.random_number(5,fix_len=True), "hhs": 
fake.random_number(3),"pop": 
fake.random_number(4),"area": 
rn.randint(1,2)} for x in range(100)])
frame_fake = frame_fake.drop_duplicates('enum_area',keep='last').sort_values(by='enum_area',ascending=True)
frame_fake = frame_fake.reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
```

Here is the updated code for stratified sampling which now works.

```
def stratified_custom(data,strata,sample_size, seed=None):
    data = data.copy() 
    data['strat_size'] = data.groupby(strata)[strata].transform('count')
    try: 
        data['strat_sample_size'] = data[strata].map(sample_size)
        smp_size = data.set_index(strata)['strat_sample_size'].to_dict()
        strat2_sample = (data.groupby(strata, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(smp_size[x.name],random_state=seed)))
        strat2_sample['inclusion_prob'] = strat2_sample['strat_sample_size']/strat2_sample['strat_size']
        return strat2_sample
    except:
        data['strat_sample_size'] = sample_size
        strat2_sample = (data.groupby(strata, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(sample_size,random_state=seed)))
        strat2_sample['inclusion_prob'] = strat2_sample['strat_sample_size']/strat2_sample['strat_size']
        return strat2_sample

s_size={1:3,2:9,3:5,4:5,5:5,6:5,7:5,8:5,9:8} 
variablesize = (stratified_custom(data=frame_fake,strata='region',sample_size=s_size, seed=99).sort_values(by=['region','enum_area'],ascending=True)).head()
variablesize 
fixedsize = (stratified_custom(data=frame_fake,strata='region',sample_size=3, seed=99).sort_values(by=['region','enum_area'],ascending=True)).head()
fixedsize
```

The output of variable sample size:

```
region  district  enum_area  ...  strat_size  strat_sample_size  inclusion_prob
5        1        60      14737  ...           5                  3             0.6
26       1        42      34017  ...           5                  3             0.6
68       1        31      72092  ...           5                  3             0.6
0        2        65      10566  ...          10                  9             0.9
15       2        22      25560  ...          10                  9             0.9
```

The output of fixed sample size:

```
    region  district  enum_area  ...  strat_size  strat_sample_size  inclusion_prob
5        1        60      14737  ...           5                  3             0.6
26       1        42      34017  ...           5                  3             0.6
68       1        31      72092  ...           5                  3             0.6
38       2        74      48408  ...          10                  3             0.3
43       2        15      56365  ...          10                  3             0.3
```

I was however wondering if there is a better way of achieving this?